# How to connect unused package pins to VCC on a Spartan 3E FPGA?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, spartan

I would like to turn off the four sevent segment display on my Nexys2 board.

After referring to the [datasheet](https://ece.umd.edu/class/enee245.F2016/nexys2_reference_manual.pdf), I figured that if I could connect the pins labeled "F17", "H17", "C18" and "F15" (as shown in the figure below) to VCC, all four seven segments would turn off.

[image]

Is there any way of doing this other than creating 4 inputs, assigning them to the four locations above in a UCF file and then driving them high  :

```vhdl
net "sevenseg1" loc ="F17";
net "sevenseg2" loc ="H17";
net "sevenseg3" loc ="C18";
net "sevenseg4" loc ="F15";
```

in conjunction with:

```vhdl
sevenseg1,sevenseg2,sevenseg3,sevenseg4: in std_logic :='1';
```

P.S. I'm using the ISE Design Suite 14.7.

Comment: You should make them **outputs** and set them high. No there is no simpler way: that is the standard solution.

Comment: How about commenting cathodes/dp out of the UCF? (Not just LOC)

Comment: Another possibility is to edit configuration options, set unused iob pins to use pull up resistors, and ignore segment pins (not include in design) completely. But that's global, and might conflict with other components connected to fpga. You'll need to check with the board schematics first.